# Showing that given function is differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am trying the following question from a competitive exam :

I need to show that the following function is differentiable : 
f : $R$ --> $R$ defined as 
f(x) = $(1-x^2)$^$(3/2)$ if x is in (-1,1) and f(x)
     = 0 if x is in R-(-1,1)

I know that the function is differentiable when it is constant. So I need to show that it is differentiable in (-1,1). I tried the limit definition but I'm not able to evaluate the limit.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think you can use known facts for $-1\lt x\lt 1$ (as well as for $|x|\gt 1$, but you already did). The only issue is at $x=\pm 1$. There I think you are expected to use the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use the fact that $$f'(h)=\lim_{h\to c} \frac{f(h)-f(c)}{h-c}$$. The function is differentiable if the limit exists. As Andre Nicholas pointed out consider the points $x=\pm 1$